# 301 Single Page Redirects Going To 404s

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

OK, so I'm trying to redirect an old site, as well as its subpages to specific subpages and while the root redirects fine, the specific subpages don't redirect to what I've specified, instead going to 404s.  The old site is www.csulb.edu/web/journals/riprap/, and as you can see, if you go to that site it redirects to the new site.  But the subpages within it are not redirecting.  Here is my .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprapjournal/
Redirect 301 /submission_guidelines.htm http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-journal-submission-guidelines/
Redirect 301 /backissues.htm http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-backissues/
Redirect 301 /links.htm http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-links/
Redirect 301 /contact.htm http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-contact/
```

What is the problem with this?  The first 301 redirect is trying to tell www.csulb.edu/web/journals/riprap/submission_guidelines.htm to go to http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-journal-submission-guidelines/, but it goes to a 404 page.  Please help!

Comment: What's the URL that appears in your URL location bar when you get redirected? Are you not getting redirected at all? What URL are you going to that isn't redirecting? Do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: Well when I go to the "Submission Guideline" one, for example, it goes to http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprapjournal/submission_guidelines.htm, when it is supposed to go to http://www.csulb.edu/colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-journal-submission-guidelines/

I posted the entire .htaccess file above, what you see is all that's there.

Comment: Where are these rules located?

Comment: In the .htaccess file which is in the root folder of the site I'm trying to redirect.

Comment: The problem was solved...it was a caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RedirectMatch ^/$ /colleges/cla/departments/english/riprapjournal/
Redirect 301 submission_guidelines.htm /colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-journal-submission-guidelines/
Redirect 301 backissues.htm /colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-backissues/
Redirect 301 links.htm /colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-links/
Redirect 301 contact.htm /colleges/cla/departments/english/riprap-contact/
```

Comment: Nope, same problem.  Do you think the problem has something to do with me trying to redirect a single .htm page to a subdirectory?  Or the fact that this is on WordPress?  This is really frustrating.

Comment: Also, is it a problem that your code didn't have the line that says "RewriteEngine on"?

Comment: What is the location of your .htaccess?

Comment: In the root folder of the old site.

Comment: Can you try it out a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.  It was a caching issue.  Thanks for your help man, I really appreciate it!

Comment: If this answer/comments helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.